# Do I need to have Android Studio for building flutter apps?

Tags: android

For some reason, Android Studio is slow on my computer. I got other text editors as well. But what are my solutions?
I am looking forward to learn mobile app development.
Any suggestions are appreciated..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to install Android Studio for flutter or what can be replacement for android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177064/is-it-necessary-to-install-android-studio-for-flutter-or-what-can-be-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flutter run` or `flutter build apk` from the **flutter commandline** (run flutter_console.bat in your installation directory on windows).

If you use VS Code, you can easily install the flutter extension and run your app with the press of a button or (Ctrl+Shift+D). Or press `Ctrl+Shift+D` and type `flutter:` in order to see the available options (e.g. create a new project).